# Setting up ACL permission - creating new directory applies wrong filter (default problems)

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, acl

When I run the below I get the below ACL settings. The problem exists when I create a new directory. For some reason, the default ACL parameters are not being passed to the new dir

```
AppUser1@r01mgt:~ $ hadoop fs -getfacl /somedir/
# file: /somedir
# owner: Owner1
# group: Group1
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:Group2:r-x
group:Group3:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:Group2:r-x
default:group:Group3:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x



--CREATE new dir


AppUser1@r01mgt:~ $ hadoop fs -getfacl /somedir/somedir
# file: /somedir
# owner: Owner1
# group: Group1
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:Group2:r-x
group:Group3:rwx     #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:Group2:r-x
default:group:Group3:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

does anyone know why my group:Group3:rwx becomes effective r-x? and why my mask becomes r-x? Is this because of umask?

thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [HDFS-6962](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6962)  ***ACLs inheritance conflict with umaskmode***

In a nutshell:

> ... HDFS masks the ACL value (user, group and other – except the POSIX
>   owner) with the group mask of `dfs.umaskmode` properties when creating
>   directory with inherited ACL.  ... this is a divergence from the POSIX
>   ACL specs.
>
> ... it's impossible to make this change in a backwards-compatible way
>   in the 2.x line ... if someone upgrades the client ahead of the
>   NameNode ... neither the client nor the NameNode would apply the umask
>   ... which of course would compromise security.
>
> I'm retargeting this to 3.0.0.